# Dealing with anger

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits

What is a good sefer or even book that helps people with a problem with getting angry?

Comment: Answers to this question would be most useful, I think, if accompanied by a testimonial of having personally found the book useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall a sefer called (I think) Erech Apaim.  In addition, working on middos such as ga'ava and bitachon would be useful.

I didn't think of it as a Hebrewbooks type of sefer, but [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/36225) it is.

comment: actually. there is an english translation here:
http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=247

Comment: I heard about it is it available in English

Comment: I doubt it since I haven't seen it widely circulated, though I recall that it is easy Hebrew.  I don't remember the name of the author.  I do remember part of his intro:  He says the reason that Korach was wrong and that a Techeiles Talis still needs a techeiles pesil and a room with sifrei torah still needs a mezuza is that they require an exclusive mnemonic to accomplish their purpose (the pesil/mezuza).  So too, working on anger requires an exclusive approach and general middah perfection will only go so far.

Answer (score 8):

The range of sources that discuss anger in Jewish tradition is huge.

There is a sefer I saw called *Haser Ka'as Milibecha*, (Translated as "[Remove Anger from Your Heart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1607630362)"), a classic mussar work compiled by Rav Avraham Tubolsky, shlit"a.

Gan Emunah (available in English as "The Garden of Peace") discusses it, and I bet Gan HaShalom does as well. Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh (Available in English as "[Building a sanctuary in your heart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00538J4WY)") also discuss this.

Oroḥt Zadikim discusses it (but to take full advantage of that sefer, you have to have an understanding of how to learn mussar), and Alei Shur provides exercises regarding anger (and lots of guidance about the mussar derech in general, and lots of exercises for improving other middot as well -- this can help with using Oroḥt Zadikim).

The hard part isn't finding books or reading about it -- it's internalizing what the books have to say.

Comment: +1 for Haser Kaas Milibecha. It is the best, and it is one of my rebbeyim who authored it. It is downloadable for your Kindle reader, and you can find it [here on Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B005JVSHKU) for only $9.99.

Answer (score 5):

There's a book by Rabbi Zelig Pliskin called 'Anger: the inner teacher', it's very clear and set out step by step.

Comment: Abi, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for referencing this potentially useful book! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member which you can accomplish by clicking on "register," above.

Answer (score 3):

[The Dance of Anger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006074104X). The subtitle shouldn't discourage men, either.

Comment: Did you have a good experience with it?

Comment: Yes. I wish I could remember more of it so as to give a review with more specificity. Also, like with everything, you must judiciously sift the information you receive.

Answer (score 2):

Igeres Haramban read and studied once a week has helped me for many years.

Comment: @sabbahillel I'm not sure what requires more clarification in this answer more than many previous answers. Sol believes Iggeret HaRaMBa"N helps with anger (I don't disagree).

Answer (score 0):

The Trail To Tranquility by Rabbi Brody is my favorite:
[here it is on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1595261087)